# Google Workbox not intercepting POST requests

Tags: caching, service-worker, workbox

I am trying to intercept POST requests using a serviceworker with Workbox. However the route does not seem to register. When online the request just goes through and nothing is logged. When offline the console logges an *net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED* error. The request also does not seem to fall into the catchHandler.

**service-worker.js**

```
registerRoute(
    ({url}) => url.pathname.endsWith('detailScreen'),
    ({request, url}) => {
        console.log('POST', request, url)
    },
    'POST')

setCatchHandler(async options => {
    console.log(options.request, options.url)
    return Response.error();
})
```

**request:**
`https://test.com/admin/crm/relation/detailScreen`

Comment: Can you post a link to your web app or host a live example on a site like glitch.com? Do other requests, like `GET`s, get intercepted by the service worker? What you're describing should, in general, work.

Comment: The problem is fixed now, but I can't remember why it didn't work. Probably a mistake on my end.